# Insertion with Regex to format a date (Perl)

Tags: regex, perl

Suppose I have a string 04032010.
I want it to be 04/03/2010. How would I insert the slashes with a regex?

Comment: Just as a side note, is that supposed to be fourth of march, or third of april?  I would always convert to a yyyy-mm-dd format (ISO 8601) for disambiguation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, a regular expression just matches, but you can try something like this:
s/(..)(..)(..)/$1/$2/$3/

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

$var = "04032010";
$var =~ s/(..)(..)(....)/$1\/$2\/$3/;
print $var, "\n";
```

Works for me:

```
$ perl perltest
04/03/2010
```

Answer (score 4):

To do this with a regex, try the following:

```
my $var = "04032010";
$var =~ s{ (\d{2}) (\d{2}) (\d{4}) }{$1/$2/$3}x;
print $var;
```

The `\d` means match single digit. And `{n}` means the preceding matched character n times.  Combined you get `\d{2}` to match two digits or `\d{4}` to match four digits. By surrounding each set in parenthesis the match will be stored in a variable, `$1, $2, $3` ... etc.

Some of the prior answers used a `.` to match, this is not a good thing because it'll match any character. The one we've built here is much more strict in what it'll accept.

You'll notice I used extra spacing in the regex, I used the `x` modifier to tell the engine to ignore whitespace in my regex. It can be quite helpful to make the regex a bit more readable.

Compare `s{(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{4})}{$1/$2/$3}x;` vs `s{ (\d{2}) (\d{2}) (\d{4}) }{$1/$2/$3}x;`

Answer (score 2):

I always prefer to use a different delimiter if `/` is involved so I would go for

```
s| (\d\d) (\d\d) |$1/$2/|x ;
```